# HTML and character encoding vs HTML Entity

Tags: html, character-encoding, html-entities

When writing an HTML document, is it acceptable to use the direct special character such as the captial letter C with a cedilla underneath as regular text: `Ç` or to use the [HTML Entity name](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) of this charecter, `&Ccedil` ?

I have seen both being used in practice, but surely there are rules governing the appropriate usage of this, as well as advantages to one way over another. For instance, this website maintains the raw-form of this character, but other websites may end up rendering it as a square block.

Comment: When in doubt if it's needed, and you're unsure about the entity name, you can always use a numerical entity: "Ç" (charcode 199) can be represented as "&#199;" (decimal) or as "&#xc7;" (hex). That conversion can be done by a simple conversion script.

Comment: You should be careful about that, I've seen javascripts online that goof up the conversion somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the character encoding of the document. If you're unsure of whether or not you should use the the regular text or the encoding version, you could run your page through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Consider this code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>©</p>
 <p>&#169;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The document encoding is set to UTF-8 and when it's validated, it returns an error:

> Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 7 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.

Comment: If the document was being served as UTF-8 correctly, this would work fine.

Comment: All were great answers, but I'm accepting this one because you provide a validation method.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but the W3C Validator does *not* check whether the document’s declared encoding matches its actual encoding. It can only detect incidents caused by a mismatch in some cases.

Answer (score 9):

Real characters:

- Are easier to type if your system is set up for a language that uses those characters
- Produce more readable code
- Save bytes

HTML entities:

- Let you more or less forget about character encoding

Obviously, characters with special meaning in HTML (`<`, `&`, etc) still need to be represented by entities.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using UTF-8 character encoding, then most entity characters (other than `&amp;`, `&gt;` and `&lt;`) become redundant.

If you're not using UTF-8, then you need entities for everything.

Comment: "Using UTF-8 encoding" here means "serving your pages as UTF-8 encoded."

Comment: "If you're not using UTF-8, then you need entities for everything." - not true. You need entities for anything which can't be represented in your current character encoding. "Ç" is fine in ISO-8859-1, for example.

Comment: UTF-8 is **not** the only non-ASCII encoding out there (even if it is the most appropriate encoding for the vast majority of western documents)

Comment: That's not right. If your page encoding (file format) is ISO-Latin-1 or Windows CP1252, and the webserver returns it as such, then "Ç" (=chr(199)) will work fine. But when in doubt, entities is safer.

Comment: @everyone - yes, I know I simplified it down to UTF-8 or bust. But frankly, if you're going to specify anything other than the default, you may just as well pick UTF-8. Anyway, all good points. Thank you.